# Strange behaviour of mean() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

I'm trying to calculate per-column mean for matrix using Matlab and see strange behaviour.

Matlab calculates mean() for the first and second columns, but doesn't calculate it for the rest columns.

Example:

```
    >> Z = [2104 4426816 3 9; 1600 2560000 3 9; 2400 5760000 3 9]

Z =

        2104     4426816           3           9
        1600     2560000           3           9
        2400     5760000           3           9

>> mean(Z)

ans =

   1.0e+06 *

    0.0020    4.2489    0.0000    0.0000

>> mean(Z(1:2,:))

ans =

        1852     3493408           3           9
```

The same code works perfectly using Octave:

```
octave:36> Z = [2104 4426816 3 9; 1600 2560000 3 9; 2400 5760000 3 9]
Z =

      2104   4426816         3         9
      1600   2560000         3         9
      2400   5760000         3         9

octave:37> mean(Z)
ans =

   2.0347e+03   4.2489e+06   3.0000e+00   9.0000e+00
```

Something wrong with my code?
Any idea how to calculate mean for all of columns using Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB is performing the calculation correctly, but the default number format (short-fixed) for the display makes the `3` and `9` appear to be `0` since the other numbers are large.
You can change the format using [`format`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html).
When you change it to short-exponential format, you get Octave's output (since it evidently has a different default):

```
>> format shorte;
>> mean(Z)
ans =
2.0347e+03   4.2489e+06   3.0000e+00   9.0000e+00
```

Comment: @user4510038 Not a problem.  Make sure to accept the answer so the question is complete (with a small benefit of 15 rep for me ;) ).

Comment: I'm new here, so thanks for prompting about completing question too. ;)